# Styling input elements with CSS3 by wrapping input with a label

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

CSS3 experts:

I'm trying to re-style an input checkbox, I can do it with the following style if I give each input an ID and refer to it with a label and it's "for" property:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox><label for="myCheckBox">foo</label>
```

I'd like to loose the id's to simplify so I tried wrapping the input with the label but I can't seem to figure out how to style it:

```
<label>foo<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></label>
```

This is my working CSS using IDs:

```
.checkbox {
    display:none;
}
.checkbox + label {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #333;
    padding:9px;
    border-radius:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:3px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}
.checkbox:checked + label {
    background-color: #e00000;
    border: 1px solid #e00000;
    color: #fff;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:after {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

Totally got me stumped, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Checkbox is "connected" to the label by the `id`-`for` relationship, so if you remove the id, the click on the label won't trigger the checkbox. Why would you remove the `id` on the checkbox anyway?

Comment: Right, totally understand how what I have working works.  The inputs are generated on the server-side.  I'm trying to figure out how to restyle them without modifying the server-side to add IDs to every input that's a checkbox. So, if I could wrap the inputs in their labels and then figure out the appropriate CSS3 selectors I think I'm good, that's where I'm lost.  I can fall back to doing the server-side edits but wanted to figure this out really just to figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused. So you can't change the html, only the css, is that correct? Can you provide exactly what html you have to work with?

Comment: I want/need to have my server-side code to look like this: `<label>foo<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></label>` instead of `<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox><label for="myCheckBox">foo</label>`, I want to drop the IDs (if possible).

Comment: Really, I can do it with IDs if I had to, but the reason I posted the question is so I could learn how to do it without the IDs.  In other words, how to refer to/select the `<input>` inside the `<label></label>` with CSS3.

Comment: `label > input`. And this is for any CSS version.

Comment: Read this: [Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: Thanks, MelanciaUK.  I get how to select the `<input>` but how do I style the selecting `<label>`? For example, how would I style the label by selecting as `label > input`, is there a parent selector I'm missing?

Comment: There's no parent selector unfortunately. Are you able to add the `checkbox` class to the label?

Comment: Ahh! I smell what you're stepping in .. let me to try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually go where you went with the whole adjacent sibling selector (`input + label`), but if you don't like that, you can always add a wrapping element for styling purposes.  Unfortunately it does dirty the markup a little, but I don't really see any other way to style that and not use the `id` and `for` approach.

Not ideal, but it works.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + div {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #333;
    padding:9px;
    border-radius:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:3px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {
    background-color: #e00000;
    border: 1px solid #e00000;
    color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div:after {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"><div>foo</div></label>
```